# Changing the default thumbnail size

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to change the default thumbnails size for image. Users started putting explicitly 400px everywhere, but I think it would be better to fall back to

`[[File:Flower.jpg|thumb|A flower]]`

being rendered implicitly in 400px with.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$wgThumbLimits` and `$wgDefaultUserOptions['thumbsize']` in your `LocalSettings.php` as explained in [Manual:$wgThumbLimits](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgThumbLimits).